# Center Menu.Item in semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I need help centering a title (Menu.Item) inside of a Menu using semantic-ui-react. Here is my current code:

```
render() {    
    return (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item>
          Editorials
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item>
          Reviews
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item position={"right"}>
          Upcoming Events
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
```

So this creates a menu with two items on the left and one on the right. Is there a way I can create an item in the middle of the menu? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @AziCode no I did not.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I fixed it.
I add 2 position:"right" and the first one got centered. I hope it works.

```
render() {    
  return (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item>
        Editorials
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Menu position='right'>
        <Menu.Item>
          Reviews
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu.Menu>

      <Menu.Menu position='right'>
        <Menu.Item>
          Upcoming Events
        </Menu.Item>
     </Menu.Menu>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please consider adding an explanation. Quality answers gain points over time as visitors learn something from posts that they can apply to their own current coding issues, or that can prevent future issues from occurring. Consider editing to clarify how/why this code should resolve the OP's issue.

Comment: Here is a quick explanation. Since Menu.Menu position:'right" in semantic UI has margin-left:auto!important; the first one gets centered.

Comment: Is there a way to do only left and center elements?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Maybe try this with the position of the left item set explicitly and with the syntax I've used for setting it. (ie. don't wrap the position value in curly braces)

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item position="left">
    Editorials
  </Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item>Reviews</Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item position="right">
    Upcoming Events
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```